# How do i fix user sign-in failure in Django?

Tags: django, heroku

I am experiencing an awkward moment with my Django application. I deployed my django app with heroku about a month ago, it worked fine until today, users cannot access their accounts.

I specify the link below for users to access their account after signing in

```
{% if perms.orders.recieved_order_list %}
     <li><a id="lettering" href="{% url orders.recieved_order_list %}">Admin</a></li>
     {% endif %}
```

It is working fine in development but the link is not showing up when user signs in via production. Also if superuser signs in via production, the link shows up.

in my settings.py, the permissions,

```
GROUP_PERMISSIONS = {
    "Administrator": ('auth.user.*','restaurant_detail.restaurant_detail.*','restaurant_detail.restaurant_read','orders.order.*','orders.orderItem.*','orders.orderitem.*','orders.orderitem_list','orders.order.*','orders.recieved_order.*','django_quickblocks.quickblocks.*','django_quickblocks.quickblocktype.*',),
    "Restaurants": ('restaurant_detail.restaurant_myprofile','restaurant_detail.restaurant_read','restaurant_detail.item.*','restaurant_detail.category.*','orders.order.*','orders.recieved_order.*',),
}
```

`restaurant` is the user in this case and `administrator` is the superuser.

Comment: What do you mean the link does not show up?

Comment: Exactly that, it does not show up, it is not their but if superuser signs in the `admin` link shows.

Comment: Which version of Django? Please provide more detail. The current question does not give much information to try to troubleshoot the situation.

Comment: django 1.4 and i think @Krasnoperov below is on the right track, i feel its permissions problem but i don't understand how that happens since in my settings the user has permission to access recieved_order_list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your users loose permission "orders.received_order_list".
And superuser bypass all permissions checks implicitly, so link works for him.

Possible reasons:

1. Your database is corrupted and object for "received_order_list" is
   not installed. You can run python manage.py syncdb to fix missed
   objects for permissions.
2. Required permission is not set for user or 
   group. This can be fixed in admin interface.

Comment: that is what i think is happening but why is it that it is working in development.

Comment: Another possible reason: your database can be corrupted and object for "received_order_list" is not installed. You can run `python manage.py syncdb` to fix missed objects for permissions.

Comment: will answer here: permission is assigned to user not through settings.py, but through relation in database. You can assign permission directly to user. Or you can assign permission to group and add user in that group.

Comment: i actually reset the database the first time round. it didnt help so i turned to stack overflow..

Comment: Hey buddy,i just did another syncdb and it worked, i still don't get how it missed the permissions the first time around. edit your answer so i can accept it.

Comment: What should I place in answer? Is current version okey for you?

Comment: sorry i had run off but that did fine